# VS2012 setup spoils SQL Server 2012 Data Tools for everybody or just me?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, visual-studio-2012

On Windows 7 Prof I have installed SQL Server 2012 R2 with, as I am pretty well remember, client tools.

Then, I tried to install Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate but failed.
Then I've installed VS2012 Prof (30-day trial).

Now, on launching SQL Server 2012 (i.e. VS2010 Shell)) Data Tools --> New Project I am getting:

[image: On launching SQL Server 2012 (i.e. VS2010 Shell)) Data Tools --> New Project]

Fig.1.1. On launching SQL Server 2012 (i.e. VS2010 Shell)) Data Tools --> New Project

and on pressing OK button

[image]

Fig.1.2.

telling:

- "The operation you are attempting requires Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools to be installed"  though I am somewhat sure I'have installed SQL Server Data Tools...

Also, a book on SQL Server 2012  I am reading tells me that in such situation I should see (to choose) "**SQL Server Database project**" template (which is absent in my case)

When I launch VS2012 --> choose New Project ,  I see **SQL Server Database project template**

[image]
Fig.2.1.

but on pressing OK button, I get

[image]
Fig.2.2

- "This version of SQL Server Data Tools is not compatible with database runtime components installed on this computer"

  Also, I cannot rely on this since I am developing against machines with SQL Server 2012 but without VS2012

After installing [Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014) then [Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015) from [Download SQL Server Data Tools - October 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027), everething seems started to work but I am eager to understand whether VS2012 setup damages SQL Server 2012 (i.e. VS2010 Shell) Data Tools for everybody or just me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my installation of VS 2012 (Premium). I installed VS 2012, at the custom installation options screen I chose the option for SSDT, but when actually using it, it was really absent (same error as yours).

My idea is that the default installer only adds the template for the project, but not SSDT itself. I also had to install SSDT separately (in this case only for VS 2012) and it worked (SSDT for VS 2010 is necessary only if you want to open SQL projects in VS 2010, but I guess you know that already).